# Underline to specific text - FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a table created using FPDF. My problem is how to add an underline to specific text?

For example,

Name | Gender | Age

Dame | Female | 20

I want the "Name, Gender & Age" is underlined

This is my code so far

```
$p->Cell(20,5,'Name','LTR',0,'C',0);
$p->Cell(40,5,'Gender','TR',0,'C',0);
$p->Cell(40,5,'Age','TR',0,'C',0);

while(retrieve from DB)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`SetFont`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setfont.htm) for underlines. You can leave the font family blank to keep it the same.

```
$p->SetFont('','U');
$p->Cell(20,5,'Name','LTR',0,'C',0);
```

Comment: If i add this code, the other cell after "Name" will also underline...how to overcome this?

Comment: Use `SetFont` again to return to the font to a non-underlined state.